# Add custome utility JAR to Windows System Path

Tags: java, windows, jar, path

Is it possible to add a utility jar to Window's System Path?

I have `findclass.jar` that is an exicutable jar located in my `C:\` directory.
 
If I open cmd.exe, change directories to `C:\`, and type:
 
`java -jar findclass.jar \path\tojar.jar nameofclass.class` 
it will search another jar for a given class.

How can I add findclass.jar to my Window's System Path so I don't need to change directories to `C:\`?
I tried  `set path=C:\;%PATH%` and `set path=C:\findclass.jar;%PATH%`
but I get `Error: Unable to access jarfile findclass.jar` when I try to execute it from a different directroy.

Is it not possible to add a .jar file to the path?

Answer (score 1):

Add it to CLASSPATH environment variable.

Comment: Still getting `Error: Unable to access jarfile findclass.jar`

Comment: `>set classpath=C:\findclass.jar;%CLASSPATH% > java -jar findclass.jar \path\tojar.jar nameofclass.class` still results in `>Error: Unable to access jarfile findclass.jar` unless I cd into C:\